# How to deserialize JSON values in C# and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I need to fetch some values obtained from an web URL.
The JSON is as given:

```
{"country":{"name":"India","State":"Raj": Count :239}, "Population": 25487}
```

Now i want to fetch the value of Count and Population using C#.

I have tried using `JavaScriptSerializer();` But the problem is that its response time is much much slower.

Please suggest me a way to fetch the values from this JSON string.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally use

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

It's a very fast JSON serializer/deserializer.

I usually create an extension method to make the code tidier:

```
    public static string ToJson(this object _obj)
    {

        return JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(_obj);
    }
```

Edit:

A quick way to fetch those values would be to create a class of the data:

```
public class Country
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class CountryInformation
{
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using ServiceStack:

```
void SomeFunction(string _Json)
{
    var FeedResult = _Json.FromJson<CountryInformation>();
}
```

You can then get the values from FeedResult as such:

FeedResult.Country.name;

Comment: Also recent versions of ServiceStack.Text comes with `ToJson<T>()` and `FromJson<T>()` extension methods :)

Comment: Sir can you please write c# code for me if i am getting JSON from a web url www.xyz.com..... and suppose it gives the JSON shown above. Now how can i get the values using ServiceStack and print them in a label (say)... Hope you will code a little bit more me....Thanks

Comment: -1 Problem changed from `the problem is that its response time is much much slower.Please suggest me a way to fetch the values from this JSON string`  to  `Sir can you please write c# code for me`

Comment: Although i have done it but Sir some of the JSON values contains [{json values}] Square brackets and in that case it throws an exception. So how to deal with that ?

Comment: @iKunu if it is wrapped in `[]` brackets, you'll want to use `json.FromJson<CountryInformation[]>()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Json.NET - http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I normally recommend using typed POCO's like @misterjingo suggested. 
However for one-off tasks you can use [ServiceStack's Json Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/) to parse it dynamically like:

```
var json = "{\"country\":{\"name\":\"India\",\"State\":\"Raj\": \"Count\": 239}, \"Population\": 25487}";

var jsonObj = JsonObject.Parse(json);
var country = jsonObj.Object("country");

Console.WriteLine("Country Name: {0}, State: {1}, Count: {2} | Population: {3}",
    country["name"], country["State"], country["Count"], jsonObj["Population"]);

//Outputs:
//Country Name: India, State: Raj, Count: 239 | Population: 25487
```

Note: the [JSON spec](http://json.org/) requires an object property name to be a string which is always double quoted.

ServiceStack's JsonSerializer is also the fastest Json Serializer for .NET [much faster than other Json Serializers](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the newer [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class to work with JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use DataContractSerialiser (ideally if you create the feed) and if you have a tricky malformed json string use JSON.net as it gives you linq2json to parse through it one node at a time.